# route works only first time after page load

Tags: angular, routes, angular-material2

Hy,

Can anyone tell me why my routing works only one time after loading the page?

f.e.:

page load (works)-> select book1 (works)-> select other (not working)

or

page load (works)-> select book2 (works) -> select other (not working)

and etc.

[my example](https://embed.plnkr.co/zHQ0wXccQrVDxvRbvgiz/)

What did I miss?

Any other suggestions would be very nice too.

Comment: Your route is actually working but the component is being reused by angular

Comment: okey, so which file makes problem and can you tell me how should I fix my problem to make not-reusing because I am new too angular and actually I don`t see where reuse happens

Comment: I've posted an answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your example working you need to set up a subscription for when the route params change.

This can be done in the following way:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((parms: any) => {            
        if (parms.laikID) {
            this.atsakymas = this.books.getBook(parms.laikID);
            this.ats = JSON.stringify(this.atsakymas);
        }
    });
}
```

That will work with your example. However you should probably look into using data binding rather than having a subscription on the route params.

Comment: works. Thank you. I`ll consider about binding too. Can you tell me does using of subscription have some disadvantages in contrast of binding?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. You could also have an event on a button instead of a router link. Then you would write something like (click)="onClicked('laikID')" to trigger call to your component method.

Comment: You see, actually I use database on my desktop development and so I use subsribe because I am new to angular2 and I found lost of examples which prefer using subscribing. And here I made example with simple arrays as the alternative to database.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to use subscription for many use cases so if it's a good fit for your use case all well then surely you can use that. Please accept the answer that helped you the most in order to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your component is being reused because nothing changes except the paramater in the url

```
constructor(private http: HttpService,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private books:Books) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
        const laikID = params['laikID'];

        console.log(laikID);
    });
}
```

Try the above code out in your NaujaiGautiComponent this will console log the change every time you change the route.

Good luck!

Comment: sorry, what is channelId here? how to get it?

Comment: @user7234965 sorry copy paste error I've edit my answer

Comment: thank you for answering but I don`t understand your idea to log the number. What did you want me to find out? I already knew that number changes everytime I click link.

Comment: @user7234965 to prove how it works in your example logging wouldn't print the new number on a route change with the above code it'll print the updated id on Route change

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help, but your code is hard to follow - I guess language barrier on my part.  I suggest to you that you create a simple project with just 2 components - see if you can router between the components.  Make sure you have a menu - don't manually navigate.  Once you get that working then you can move forward or you can re-ask the question